# i have 2 files index.php and css files. index.php is worked correctly bud css is not working why?

Tags: php, html, css, indexing

my index is:

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <title>collapaing Header</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <header>
    <h1>This is my header </h1>
  </header>
  <div id="banner">
    <h2> This is the banner </h2>
  </div>
  <div id="content">
    <p>Content goes here </p>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

my css is:

```
body{
  text-align: center;

}
header{
  height: 100px;
  background: #dbdbdb;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 10;
}
.banner{
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  background: #707070;
}

.content{
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  top: 400px;
  height: 1500px;
}
```

Comment: Really? You put every string in a `\``?

Comment: "not working" - We really don't know how should work... so, describe the problem.

Comment: My CSS Isn't Working apply nothing

Comment: maybe because this line does not end properly:  <meta charset="utf-8"

Comment: @bas schreuder tanq for comment but no its not

Answer (score -1, accepted):

firstly, close the meta tag ,
and
try not self closing the link tag ,
check whether the css file is in the same folder of that of html file

Comment: tanq for answer but still is not work

Comment: try using addding doctype html tag at the top of html code

Comment: or try using internal css using style tag in head tag

Answer (score 1):

1. Your CSS is working, when I test it.
2. Your meta tag needs the ending `/>`, right now it is not properly closed.
3. Number 2 should fix your problem, if not, make sure `style.css` is in the same directory as `index.php`.